# Implementing testing automation for asp.net

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I have planned to implement automated testing for our web application .I want the tool to be open source, test cases should be written in C sharp.

So i choose to use selenium Web-driver and N-unit. I have a set of questions.

Can i only unit testing with this setup? Cannot do function testing?

Comment: Your first question is not suited for Stackoverflow. Consider removing it.

Comment: Regarding putting this question on hold - its my honest opinion that the question itself is one I encountered when I started off with selenium. I believe barring the first question its OK. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I'll avoid answering your first question as it's not suited for StackOverflow :)

> Can i only unit testing with this setup? Cannot do function testing?

You can use Selenium with a wide range of tasks.

- I started off doing unit testing of individual components of our web application.
- Then I moved on to functionally testing the end-to-end behavior.
- Currently I'm doing massive stress testing with hundreds of concurrent browser sessions.

All using Selenium.

> Should i have to write all test cases as methods?

As far as I know (and I don't know a lot), the most flexibility is attained when you conceptualize your testing architecture this way.